# Как найти файл через glob и открыть его?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос, glob

Есть проблема, хочу найти файл через модуль glob и открыть его, но при запуске кода получаю следующую ошибку:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Visual Studio\\Python\\['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\My Files\\sound.wav']"
```

Также происходит и с `winsound.PlaySound(str(sound), winsound.SND_FILENAME + winsound.SND_LOOP)`

Я в принципе понимаю в чём проблема, но как её решить?

Вот сам код:

```
import os, winsound, glob

sound = glob.glob(f'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\**\\*.wav')

def openFolder():
    print(str(sound))
    os.startfile(os.path.realpath(str(sound)))
    winsound.PlaySound(str(sound), winsound.SND_FILENAME + winsound.SND_LOOP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    openFolder()
```

Comment: А зачем вы преобразовываете список строк в строку? Если в списке `sound` уже лежит путь к нужному вам файлу, то просто возьмите его без лишних заморочек: `os.startfile(sound[0])`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop')

def some_function_for_playback(wav_file: Path):
    pass

for item in root.rglob('*.wav'):
    if item.is_file():
        some_function_for_playback(item)
```

Или для одного файла можно так:

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop')

def some_function_for_playback(wav_file: Path):
    pass

file, *_ = [*root.rglob('*.wav')] or (None,)
if file:
    some_function_for_playback(file)
```